# destFileName not used by maven-dependency-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm sure this was working!

I have a maven dependency plugin config to put a java service wrapper into a particular folder in an appassembler target folder.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>org.tanukisoftware</groupId>
                <artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <classifier>${target.arch.classifier}</classifier>
                <type>jar</type>
                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/jsw/projectnamehere/lib</outputDirectory>
                <destFileName>wrapper-${target.arch}.dll</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it gets written as wrapper.dll (which is the filename in the repo).  target.arch is set to "windows-x86-32".

Here's part of the log file:

```
[DEBUG]   (s) groupId = org.tanukisoftware
[DEBUG]   (s) artifactId = wrapper
[DEBUG]   (s) version = 3.2.1
[DEBUG]   (s) classifier = win32
[DEBUG]   (s) type = jar
[DEBUG]   (s) overWrite = true
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = <projectfolder>\target\appassembler\jsw\SophisToTradeCacheConsumer\lib
[DEBUG]   (s) destFileName = wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll
...
[DEBUG]   (f) outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = <projectfolder>\target\dependency
[DEBUG]   (s) overWriteIfNewer = true
[DEBUG]   (s) overWriteReleases = false
[DEBUG]   (s) overWriteSnapshots = false
...
[INFO] [dependency:unpack {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.tanukisoftware:wrapper:win32:3.2.1:jar
[INFO] Unpacking C:\WORK\maven\repository\org\tanukisoftware\wrapper\3.2.1\wrapper-3.2.1-win32.jarto
 <projectfolder>\target\appassembler\jsw\SophisToTradeCacheConsumer\lib
with Includes null and excludes:null
[DEBUG] Expanding: C:\WORK\maven\repository\org\tanukisoftware\wrapper\3.2.1\wrapper-3.2.1-win32.jar into <projectfolder>\target\appassembler\jsw\SophisToTradeCacheConsumer\lib
[DEBUG] expand complete
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you are using [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) but this goal (logically) doesn't support `destFileName` (a destination filename doesn't really make sense when unpacking file**s**).

In your case, either use the "final name" when packaging your dll. Or do some post processing using the Maven AntRun Plugin to rename the file.

Comment: Hmm, I kind of think that if destFileName is provided then the plugin should honour it, but we are where we are.

Comment: @Paul Well, you can try to submit a RFE but in my opinion, it doesn't make sense to provide a (unique) destination file name for the (multiple) file names included in an archive.

Comment: no, you're probably right. Would be nice if the plugin said something about ignoring the destfilename tag however.

Comment: Seems this page needs to be updated, then https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html